# postgres count customers with 2 or more orders

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get monthly numbers of customers who made 2 or more orders. I'm not that good with postgresql so any help would be appreciated.

Table name is shop_orders
Relevant columns are 'email' - customer, 'status_code' should have value 'CONFIRMED', date - timestamp.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select EXTRACT(month FROM datecolumn ) as month,email
from shop_orders
where status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
group by EXTRACT(month FROM datecolumn ),email
having count(1) >2
```

Comment: That looks good but I'm wondering how to return array of numbers for each month. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3729867 I've added month column